# Undo general preventDefault on single element?

Tags: javascript

In my mobile web app, I have this

```
//Prevent scrolling in entire document
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
```

..which makes it look a lot less 'webby' since the body can't be scrolled.

Unfortunately, this is also stopping an input slider I have from working (iPhone only, works fine in chrome)

```
<input type="range" class="slider"  min="1" max="50">
```

How do I reverse the preventDefault for this specific element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.className.indexOf('slider')==-1)
     e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check e.target and preventDefault only when the target is not an input of type range

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
   var $target = $(e.target);
   if($target.is('input') && $target.attr('type') === 'range'){
     //do nothing
   }else{
     e.preventDefault(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How can do like this , wherever this class slider is being used do something other than preventDefault

```
 document.ontouchmove = function(e){
      if(e.target.hasClass('slider'))
         { //dosomething  }
       else
{   e.preventDefault(); 
}
    }
```